# perform arithmetic operation using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to perform either of the two arithmetic operation when the condition is met:

I have FILE contains:

```
 2,8,123,VT
 60,32,456,DU
```

when it's VT,

```
 awk -F, '{ans = sprintf ("%.0f",($1 + $2) / 10); print ans}'
```

when its DU,

```
 awk -F, '{quo = $3 / 60); print qou}'
```

and the answer should be added to the file. For example, after calculating above computations:

```
 2,8,123,VT,1
 60,32,456,DU,2
```

Can I use awk for this? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '$(NF-1)=="VT"{p = sprintf("%.0f",($1 + $2) / 10)}
                  $(NF-1)=="DU"{p = $3 / 60} {print $0, p}' file
2,8,123,VT,1,1
60,32,456,DU,2,7.6
```

Comment: I'd have used `$NF == "VT"` and `$NF == "DU"` as conditions to avoid matching `AVT` and `BDU`, but this works for the given input, so ++.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the output in my question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How are you getting `,1` and `,2` in the end?

Comment: @anubhava I think you took the desired output as input, in which case the actual solution would have to use `$NF` instead of `$(NF - 1)`. I can't be sure, though; the desired output doesn't seem to make any sense, given that `456 / 60 != 2`.